# In context of Python Raw string

Tags: python, string, rawstring

My Python version is:

```
~$ python --version  
Python 2.6.6
```

I tried following in Python (I wants to show all):

1:  `\` use as escape sequence

```
>>> str('Let\'s Python')       
"Let's Python"
```

2:  `\` use as escape sequence

```
>>> 'Let\'s Python'             
"Let's Python"
```

3: `str()` and print as value not type

```
>>> print 'Let\'s Python'       
Let's Python
```

4:  its Python a raw string

```
>>> repr('Let\'s Python')      
'"Let\'s Python"'
```

[**QUESTION**]

5:  Python raw string

```
>>> print r'Let\'s Python'    
Let\'s Python
```

6: This, I do not understand followings:

```
>>> r'Let\'s Python'            
"Let\\'s Python"

>>> r'\\'
'\\\\'
```

Why `\\` ?  Why output in `5` and `6` are different?
`r`  and `repr()` are same not same?
Also please explain about internal representation of `string`  and `raw strings` are same or different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are confusing raw string literals `r''` with string representations. There is a big difference. `repr()` and `r''` are *not* the same thing.

`r''` raw string literals produce a string just like a normal string literal does, with the exception to how it handles escape codes. The produced result is still a python string. You can produce the same strings using either a raw string literal or a normal string literal:

```
>>> r'String with \n escape ignored'
'String with \\n escape ignored'
>>> 'String with \\n escape ignored'
'String with \\n escape ignored'
```

When not using a `r''` raw string literal I had to double the slash to escape it, otherwise it would be interpreted as the newline character. I didn't have to escape it when using the `r''` syntax because it does not interpret escape codes such as `\n` at all. The *output*, the resulting python string *value*, is exactly the same:

```
>>> r'String with \n escape ignored' == 'String with \\n escape ignored'
True
```

The interpreter is using `repr()` to echo those values back to us; the *representation* of the python value is produced:

```
>>> print 'String'
String
>>> print repr('String')
'String'
>>> 'String'
'String'
>>> repr('String')
"'String'"
```

Notice how the `repr()` result includes the quotes. When we echo just the `repr()` of a string, the result is *itself* a string, so it has *two* sets of quotes. The other `"` quotes mark the start and end of the result of `repr()`, and contained *within* that is the string representation of the python string `String`.

So `r''` is a syntax to *produce* python strings, `repr()` is a method to produce strings that represent a python value. `repr()` also works on other python values:

```
>>> print repr(1)
1
>>> repr(1)
'1'
```

The `1` integer is represented as a string `'1'` (the character `1` in a string).

Comment: Thanks Martijn!...Although I still not understood why `>>> print r 'String with \n escape ignored'` prints  `String with \n escape ignored` ...single `\`  ,

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Now try that without the `r` (don't change anything else). The `\n` becomes a newline.

Comment: Another thing to show the difference: `len(r'\n')` versus `len('\n')`. The first is *two* characters, a ``\`` backslash and an `n`, the other is *one* character, a newline.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters. Is there any `raw_repr(r"too many \\\ ")` function that prints the argument back exactly the same, including the `r' prefix? The output or `repr()` is unreadable. `len()` and `binascii` workarounds are not fun at all.

Comment: @MarcH no, there isn’t. There is a single canonical representation.

Comment: I found this in the mean time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778571/how-do-i-get-the-raw-representation-of-a-string-in-python. Spoiler alert: it's no silver bullet.