# Print confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python when i try to print "\20%" that is

```
>>>"\20%"
```

why is the shell printing '\x10%' that is, it is showing

```
'\x10%'
```

the same is happening with join also when is do

```
>>>l = ['test','case']
>>>"\20%".join(l)
```

it shows

```
'test\x10%case'
```

I am using python 2.7.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`'\20'` is an octal literal, and the same as `chr(2 * 8 + 0) == chr(16)`.

What the Python shell displays by default is *not* the output of print, but the `repr`esentation of the given value, which is the hexadecimal `'\x10'`.

If you want the string `\20%`, you have to either escape the backaslash (`'\\20%'`) or use a [raw string literal](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) (`r'\20%'`). Both will be displayed as

```
>>> r'\20%'
'\\20%'
```

Comment: what should the code be so that the strings gets joined as i expected

Comment: @perpetual I'm not sure what you want, but most likely it's `''\\20%'.join(l)`

Comment: i want the output to be 'test\20%case' but when i do "\\20%".join(l) it shows 'test\\20%case'

Comment: @perpetual: you're seeing the extra backslash in the `repr` of the string, but if you `print` it or write it to a file you'll see just one.

Answer (score 2):

`\20` is an escape sequence that refers to the `DLE` ASCII character whose decimal value is 16 (`20` in octal, `10` in hexadecimal). Such a character is printed as the `\x10` hex escape by the `repr` function of strings.

To specify a literal `\20`, either double the backslash (`"\\20"`) or use a raw string (`r"\20"`).

Answer (score 1):

Two print `"\20%"`

what if you print directly:

```
>>> print '\20%'
%                       # some symbol not correctly display on this page
```

and do using `r`

```
>>> print r'\20%'
\20%
>>> r'\20%'         # what r do.
'\\20%'
>>> print '\\20%'     
\20%
>>>
```

Some time back I had same doubt about string and I asked [**a question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669682/in-context-of-python-raw-string), you may find helpful

Comment: @perpetual Welcom perpetual... :)